# How to get Spring Hateoas to also return application/json

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am building a web service where my clients can only accept application/json as a response. But Spring Hateoas seems to not respect my produces in the GetMapping annotation, and always returns HAL.

I have already tried:
putting

```
spring.hateoas.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType=false
```

also in kebab case:

```
spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false
```

Also putting

```
spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json
```

I have tried putting produces=application/json in the @GetMapping annotation and in the controller.

We have also tried implementing:

```
SpringRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer...
```

None of these things worked.

Our spring boot version is 2.0.8

We expect the response json to be in application/json without the "_embedded" for a list of resources.

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Best wishes on your endeavors! Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC 3: return a Spring-Data Page as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790371/spring-mvc-3-return-a-spring-data-page-as-json)

Comment: Hi @JayRizzo, perhaps I did not ask this question properly but those articles did not really help. I am able return a JSON when "links" is an array of objects. But in the case where I need "links" to be an object of objects, it seems like HAL format is the only way to accomplish this. Is there a way to send back a JSON while links is an object of objects? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ben-yan, is this more of what you are looking for? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222580/1896134 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/25715239/1896134 or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739243/1896134